# PHP MySQL date functions

Tags: php, mysql

I am working with dates, in both PHP as well as MySQL. EVerytime I use to convert date in unix format. But this time I have taken field in DB as date. But issue is it is taking yyyy-mm-dd format. I want to store it in dd-mm-yyyy format. Is this possible if I set default setting of DB. or each time I have to explode the dd-mm-yyyy format in PHP and convert it in YYYY-MM-DD format. Its my first query.

Second query is I wish to fetch the records from today's date. I mean dates after today's date. Like today then tomorrow then so on.... Is it possible to use order by on date field.

Comment: The default output display will always be yyyy-mm-dd, but it's up to you to use `DATE_FORMAT()` in MySQL or `date(strtotime())` in PHP to put it in the format you want.  It isn't that MySQL _stores_ it as yyyy-mm-dd, just that it outputs it that way and expects it input that way.

Comment: MySQL's `STR_TO_DATE()` will also help you convert the date for insertion.

Comment: But I have to store in DD-MM-YYYY format in my DB...Is it possible...

Comment: No you don't need to store dd-mm-yyyy.  You need to convert dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd before storing it, then convert it to whatever format you wish when pulling it back out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use:

```
$date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($dateFromDB));
```

That will convert from MySQL DateTime to the format you have specified.

It is possible to order by date fields, e.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date > [yourDate]
ORDER BY date [DESC | ASC]
```

Comment: this['yourdate'] would be in default yyyy-mm-dd format of DB, right??

Comment: Ideally, you can use `$dateToCompare = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));` to convert to the MySQL format if required.

Answer (score 0):

Your second requirement contradicts with the first one.
If you store your date in `dd-mm-yyyy` format, you'll be **unable** to sort your dates.

So - yes, you have to "explode" the `dd-mm-yyyy` date in PHP or format it any other way. That's not a big deal though. Everyone does it.

Comment: hmmm... Ya though its possible every time using PHP but then I get confused on query part to find future dates from today... Means I have to pass parameter in YYYY-MM_DD format to SQL QUERY using PHP...

Answer (score -1):

If you have a field of type 'datetime' you can use the MySQL-Command: FROM_UNIXTIME(%d) for conversion. 'order by' should be no problem.

Answer (score -1):

Store the date in default format that is yyyy-mm-dd

when you want to display in front end

use the following query to

```
select otherFields, date_format(dateField,'%d-%m-%Y') from tableName;
```

For ordering  by date

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
   ORDER BY date DESC
```